# Reformatting a string number value to use minus sign instead of parentheses for negative numbers

Tags: c#, formatting

I built a service to read csv files of trade data from my new prime broker. The files show this format for negative numbers.

[image: Neg number format]

This is the code to read the file and process (only showing the part where I check for duplicate symbols since I am storing in Azure Table and cannot have duplicate symbols since the symbol is the row key)

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //check if symbol is a duplicate
            if (i>0 && records[i].Symbol == records[i - 1].Symbol)
            {    //sum the columns in records[i] and records[i-1]
                //change ent for symbol to new values
                entities[i - (1 + dupeRecords)].CommissionPl = Convert.ToDouble(records[i].CommissionPl) + Convert.ToDouble(records[i - 1].CommissionPl).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                entities[i - (1 + dupeRecords)].PositionPl = Convert.ToDouble(records[i].PositionPl) + Convert.ToDouble(records[i - 1].PositionPl).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                entities[i - (1 + dupeRecords)].TransactionPl = Convert.ToDouble(records[i].TransactionPl) + Convert.ToDouble(records[i - 1].TransactionPl).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                entities[i - (1 + dupeRecords)].TotalPl = Convert.ToDouble(records[i].TotalPl) + Convert.ToDouble(records[i - 1].TotalPl).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                // do not create new ent for this record
                //count the dupe entries for the entities index to match up
                dupeRecords++;
            }
```

The problem lies in the fact that these entries (i.e. records[i - 1].TotalPl, et al) when negative, despite showing -100 (for example) in the file show as (100) when you hover over them during processing. The Convert.ToDouble function can't process them when they are in parentheses format.

I can't figure out an EASY way to reformat the string value while iterating the records. I could check for parentheses and then strip them and multiply by -1 but I'm probably not seeing an easier solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Convert.ToDouble`, use `double.Parse` and specify the formats you allow:

```
NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign | NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
entities[i - (1 + dupeRecords)].CommissionPl = double.Parse(records[i].CommissionPl, styles)  ...
```